# Maven dependency not copied to WEB-INF\lib folder

Tags: java, maven

No matter how much I do `mvn clean install` even with `-U` this dependency (along with some other) is not being coped into the `target\app-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\lib` folder:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Not sure why this happens now, when in the **pom.xml** there is the `<packaging>war</packaging>`

**build**

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${appengine.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Copies static web files from src/main/webapp to target/${webappDirectory} -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- the exploded goal gets executed during compile phase -->
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exploded</goal>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                    <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like, but it's worth asking: What is the scope of the dependency. It is nothing so I am assuming it is not "test". Just checking. Second question. Do you have more than one "dependecies" section?

Comment: is the above jar getting downloaded in your local repo when you do a maven install

Comment: Just one "dependencies" section, I did not put a scope tag in the dependency. The one in this OP is the one in the pom.xml

Comment: @vikeng21 Yes its in the .m2 folder

Comment: try this entry in your pom  <properties>
  <keep.full.lib>true</keep.full.lib>
  <tar.artifacts>true</tar.artifacts>
 </properties> and see if it works

Comment: @vikeng21  same thing, Spring jars are not being copied

Comment: @vikeng21 I updated the OP with the build config

Comment: Please include the complete POM, could make things easier

Comment: Also, what is the `dependency:copy-dependencies` goal in the `install` phase for? It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Do you see your missing dependencies when launching `mvn dependency:tree`? Have you tried manually deleting the target directory before compiling?